# Monitor I/O of Serial Port

Tags: python-3.x, pyserial

I am creating a GUI with PyQT4 on Python 3. I however am trying to setup a serial port using PySerial that I can later implement into this GUI. I don't know how to view if the command being sent is what I want so is there a program I can use to see the correct bytes are being sent?

To be more clear: I want to see the BYTES being sent or received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pyserial's `read` and `write` methods to check what you're receiving from the peripheral and what you're sending to it. You could optionally use the method [`to_bytes`](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html?highlight=logging#serial.to_bytes) to dig deeper, even though most serial devices accept only ASCII commands.

Also, the `Serial` class has [builtin logging](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/search.html?q=logging&check_keywords=yes&area=default), you only need to enable it.

Comment: I guess I should look into the logging. However, aren't the read and write methods for communicating over this serial port? Like if I say write(':011\r') it sends this to my component, but what information do I get other than the number of bytes?

Comment: The read and write methods are indeed for communicating, but isn't that exactly what you want? When you write a string (bytestring in Python-3.x) those characters or bytes are *exactly* the bytes you're sending over the wire (encoded to ASCII in Python-2.x). If you only want to see the ones and zero, convert the string to binary representation. If you actually want to see the "hi" and "lo" states of the data wire, you'll have to dig much deeper into pyserial's code, but in the end, you'll find that they correspond to the values you get back from `read` or send via `write`.

Comment: Is your reason for asking to see the bytes perhaps related to an error or the device not responding as you expect, so your real question?

Comment: I am designing a system for someone and I'm sending a 5 byte command and receiving a 24 byte status packet and they showed me an example of this communication but it was all in bytes and I thought it would be easier from a testing standpoint for me. While I have you attention, what is the best approach for receiving a 24 byte packet at certain intervals? ( I think it's about .12 seconds in this case)

Comment: You could use `time.sleep(.12)` and then `serial.read(24)`, but eventually the clock from the host and that of the client will drift and you will lose messages. If the return packet is always 24 bytes long, you could simplu use `serial.read(24)`, which will be a blocking operation until 24 characters/bytes have been read or when the readTimeOut value has been reached (if you've set it). This latter option seems to be the most robust, provided the messages are always 24 bytes long.

Comment: If the response messages do not all have the same length, but they are delimited in the same way, you could take advantage of that (e.g. `\n` as an ending delimiter could be captured with `serial.readline()`. In most serial communications I've come across, this latter scenario is the case.